# Application for Point-To-Point Voip Call over Wifi

Tags: android, voip

I am searching for an application to make a point to point VOIP call between two android devices without having any intermediate server(SIP server) or an internet connection. I just have an access point (or multiple access point connect via LAN) and I want to make VOIP calls over WIFI only. Is that possible ?

Comment: If you can route packets between the wifi networks the devices are on, then yes. (Note that it generally would not work on mobile networks, which tend not to accept incoming connections).  This should be a fairly straightforward modification of an open source VOIP app, if it's not actually already supported.  If you are looking for something already complete off the shelf, you should ask on android.stackexchange rather than on this development site.

Comment: I Just want to use it on WiFi network, Isnt there any already made solution for that ?

Comment: The is there an already made solution question belongs on android.stackexchange.  Confusingly, if there's an OSS project that almost but not quite does it but could with modification, that belongs here...  Sounds like some web/market searches might be your first step.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, thanks for the comment, I just posted there. I didnt know about this website before. but about searching I searched alot in google and the Andoid market with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

[**servalproject**](http://www.servalproject.org/) may answer your question, although its under development. This is wifi based peer-2-peer voice calling.